# How to get query string with multiple param

Tags: c#, asp.net, url

I have a url:

```
http://www.abc.com?refurl=/english/info/test.aspx?form=1&h=test&s=AB
```

If I use

```
Request.QueryString["refurl"
```

but gives me

```
/english/info/test.aspx?form=1
```

instead I need full url

```
/english/info/test.aspx?form=1&h=test&s=AB
```

Comment: But first of all, your query string contains two `?` that is not in the correct format - and because you make this, is better to fix that. You can fix by using the `UrlEncode` function, when you add a full url string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that particular case you shouldn't use QueryString, *(since your query string contains three parameters,)*  instead use `Uri` class, and [`Uri.Query`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.query.aspx) will give you the required result.

```
Uri uri  = new Uri(@"http://www.abc.com?refurl=/english/info/test.aspx?form=1&h=test&s=AB");
string query = uri.Query;
```

Which will give you :

```
?refurl=/english/info/test.aspx?form=1&h=test&s=AB
```

Later you can remove `?refurl=` to get the desired output.

I am pretty sure there is no direct way in the framework for your particular requirement, you have to implement that in your code and that too with string operations.

Comment: It would not work if you would send more parameters (not only refurl)

Comment: @EvaldasDzimanavicius, off course it will not, but thats not in the question. Seems like the OP is interested in [Query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.query.aspx) property of the Uri

Answer (score 3):

Fix the problem, and the problem is that you place a full url as parameter `refurl` with out encoding it.

So where you create that url string use the `UrlEncode()` function, eg:

```
"http://www.abc.com?refurl=" + Server.UrlEncode(ReturnUrlParam)
```

where
`ReturnUrlParam="/english/info/test.aspx?form=1&h=test&s=AB";`

Answer (score 1):

I had similar situation some time ago.
I solved it by encoding refurl value.
now my url looks similar to that one:
http://www.abc.com?refurl=adsf45a4sdf8sf18as4f6as4fd

I have created 2 methods:

```
public string encode(string);
public string decode(string);
```

Before redirect or where you have your link, you simple encode the link and where you are reading it, decode before use:

```
Response.redirect(String.Format("http://www.abc.com?refurl={0}", encode(/english/info/test.aspx?form=1&h=test&s=AB));
```

And in the page that you are using refurl:

```
 $refUrl = Request.QueryString["refurl"];
 $refUrl = decode($refUrl);
```

EDIT:
encode/decode methods I actually have as extension methods, then for every string I can simply use `string.encode()` or `string.decode()`.

Comment: you answer is also right. I am trying to use without encoding.

Answer (score 0):

you should replace the `&` with `&amp;`.